# Mysterious anthurium disease…

Tags: identification, diseases, fungus

My friend has just acquired this beautiful Anthurium wendlingeri for me!

Sadly it had some scales and mealy bugs, which I’ve already washed off… but there is also this very strange damage:[image]
[image]
[image]

What kind of disease could this be? Fungus, bacterial damage, a virus, a fertilizer incident or just cold damage?

Should I cut the diseased leaves off? (They also happen to be the oldest…)

Should I isolate the plant?

Please help me, every information is highly appreciated!

For reference, a healthy specimen of Anthurium wendlungeri:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is very different than most Anthuriums, good question!

Comment: Yes, it’s a very special plant… that’s why I am so concerned and worried about it. Sadly there isn’t much information available about it :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe your plant is infected with a ring spot virus. It is best to get rid of this plant before it spreads to others in your collection.

Comment: Welcome to G&L.  Do you have a citation, or reference to back that up ?